# Use rows from first table to query in second table

Tags: postgresql

I wish to create a function that will iterate through the rows of one table and use the values for query of another table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test() 
RETURNS QUERY
AS $$
DECLARE
    temprow age_group%rowtype;
    q QUERY;
BEGIN
FOR temprow IN SELECT age_min, age_max FROM age_group
    LOOP
       q := q UNION SELECT * FROM data_table dt WHERE dt.age < temprow.age_max 
       and dt.age > temprow.age_min
    END LOOP;

RETURN q
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

SELECT  test();
```

The problem is that
type "QUERY' does not exist under declaration. I'm not really sure how to concatenate rows of multiple queries.
The query gets more complex  so I wish to do it with a FOR loop.

Comment: Perhaps it would be best if you explain what your function is supposed to do with a data sample and the expected results. It sounds like you can solve it with pure sql

Comment: Yes it can probably be solved with pure query but I just posted an example. I also need to do a random sample with a row limit 1000 for each attribute and and sex. It would be pretty big if it was all written here. Plus i also want to just know in general how it can be done with a FOR loop. The function just needs to return the query results.

Comment: You might just want to build the query as ```text```. Then use the ```EXECUTE``` of ```PL/pgSQL``` (docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN). Anyways, if possible I would go with @JimJones and recommend a pure SQL query, if possible.

Comment: How would one go with doing it in pure SQL? Let's say I need to do a UNION of SELECT statements that have the ages between 2 numbers. And these 2 numbers are available in each row in another table (age_group)? The problem is that these values in the table (age_group) can change so it needs to be dynamic.

Comment: So assuming table structure from your question you can do something like ```SELECT [... (whatever you need)] FROM data_table dt INNER JOIN age_group ag ON ag.age_max > dt.age AND ag.age_min < dt.age```. You can add some filters in the ```WHERE``` clause on which age groups the query shall work or group the data by their age group using ```GROUP BY```. I do not know your exact use case, but in general the answer is: use a ```JOIN```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is quite imaginary. For starters, there is no data type `query`.

You should define the function as `RETURNS SETOF data_table`.

Then call `RETURN QUERY` for each of the queries that should add another query result to the function result set:

```
FOR temprow IN
   SELECT age_min, age_max FROM age_group
LOOP
   RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM data_table dt
                WHERE dt.age < temprow.age_max 
                and dt.age > temprow.age_min;
END LOOP;

RETURN; -- from the function
```

I didn't fix all the other syntax errors like missing semicolons in your code, but this is how you write a set returning function.